# IOS audio stops after scrolling a text view

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio

I have an iPhone sound effects application in swift.   The main screen presents hints to the user in a TextView that can scroll.   On a larger phone (e.g. 6sPlus), the text does not need to scroll.  On smaller phones (e.g. 5c) the text does scroll when necessary.

My problem/challenge is…  whenever I try to scroll the TextView element, it suspends the audio that is currently playing (through a custom mixer).   If the TextView is not scrollable (because all of the text fits in the TextView), when I try to adjust the text view, the audio does not stop.

I am still researching.  I am under the impression I need to do something special with my TextView hint window to allow my application to keep playing audio after the TextView element gains focus.

Thank You for your consideration.   J

Update (later that day).  Once again thanks.  The main problem was the periodic timer for my mixer.  Once I went to scroll on the textView, the periodic choked (which stopped the audio).  Thanks again.

Comment: You probably play the music on the same thread as you scroll (read the main thread..) Check out the debugger if I am right. Then you need to somehow solve this..

Comment: It sounds like you're not using a separate thread to play the audio, but I don't know since you haven't shown any code.

Comment: I figured this was a bad design decision that I will remember for a while after I get to the bottom of this.  Thank you for the hints.   I was already using a GCD global asynchronous dispatch and I have mutiple threads going.  Your hints have given me debug ideas.  Thanks again.

Comment: u84six and Dominik - thanks again gents.  The root cause of the problem was my periodic for my audio mixer (which was getting pushed onto the background).  The periodic was then associated with the main thread, so when the TextView started to scroll, it choked my mixer periodic.   Thanks again for the hint in the right direction.